# Why does Old Norse tíu (from PGmc *tehun) have í?

Tags: old-norse

Why does Old Norse tíu (from PGmc *tehun) have í instead of é? Compare *fehu > fé.

I didn't find the answer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Norse#Phonology)

Comment: Why would you expect /VhV/ to yield a short vowel instead of a long one?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't expect "i" from PGmc "e" at all (short or long)

Comment: The latter two are entirely regular: overlong vowels are reduced, so _*ā_ and _*āa_ coincide in _*á_ a priori; and both _*ai_ and _*au_ become _á_ before _*h_, which disappears. I suggest removing those two questions, because they make it look like you’re asking why the vowels are long. Why the _*e_ becomes _*i_ in ‘ten’ is a much better question. A priori, we would expect _*tehun_ > _*tehũ_ > _*tehu_ > _*tehʷ_ > _té_ (parallel with _*fehu_ > _fé_). Why it’s treated differently is a very good question.

Comment: I edited the question based on Janus's suggestion to make it clearer what you're asking; feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think the reason is that PGmc u (from syllabic sonorant *tehun *newun) doesn't disappear but PGmc u (from non-syllabic sonorant *fehu) do.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet also I think the reason is that PGmc eu reflect Old Norse jú (drjúpa  *dreupaną, fjúka feukaną)

Why does PGmc eu reflect Old Norse jú?

Comment: Suppose it's conflated with the suffix in 16 etc. German *sechzehn* would also tend to /i/ maybe as a matter of reduced stress (I might transcribe *sechtsn* to be perfectly clear, in contrast to *Zehne* "10").

Comment: Compare Icelandic *sjaután, sjautján* "16" (en.wiktionary). Weird enough, fifteen and sixteen are not cited with such a palatal. Old Saxon and Frisian also show *sehstein, sextīne*, respectively; further West Frisian sechstjin, Dutch zestien, Old English siextīene

Comment: @vectory — *Sjaut(j)án* is Old Norse (Icelandic *sautján*) and means ‘17’, not ‘16’.

Comment: i don't remember writing this